# VCVT instruction on ARM M4-F to convert from floating point to fixed point not recognized

Tags: assembly, arm, neon, cortex-m, keil

I am trying to use the assembly instruction "vcvt.s32.f32 q8, q8, #0xf" in an ARM Cortex M4-F using the Arm Keil IDE and the compiler versions v5 and v6.

Unfortunately, this instruction is not recognized by the compiler. When I write C code, the compiler uses other slower assembly instructions in place of this one;
If I directtly write the assembly instruction, it is not accepted by the compiler leading to a compiling error.

Does anyone know anything about it?

This instruction looks present in the ARM M4-F ISA, but currently I am not able to make it works!

Comment: It assembles with the GNU assembler using `arm-none-eabi-as -mfpu=neon  -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb foo.s` in case that helps.  Are you sure M4-F has NEON SIMD, not just `-mfpu=vfpv4`?

Comment: @PeterCordes no it doesn't.

Comment: assembly language is specific to the tool and with respect to the floating point assembly languages gnu assembler supports at least two different languages for the same machine instructions.  Did you work backward and disassemble from the machine code (for your toolchain)?  As we know with gnu there is no reason to assume the disassembled assembly language is something that the assembler can assemble (certainly with arm non-floating point instructions), but it is at least a starting point.

Comment: did you try the coprocessor instruction since these are I believe simply coprocessor instructions...(mrc, mcr)?  And/or confirm they are no longer coprocessor instructions (even though the fpu is a coprocessor).

Answer (score 1):

It assembles with the GNU assembler using `arm-none-eabi-as -mfpu=neon  -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb foo.s` in case that helps.

But not with `-mcpu=cortex-m4 -mfpu=vfpv4`.

Wikipedia [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_Cortex-M#Instruction_sets) that the optional FPU on M4 is VFPv4-SP (single precision), which I think also implies that it's not full NEON.  Tom V also confirms in comments that Cortex-M4-F doesn't support this NEON SIMD instruction.

**Keil is correct -

Cortex-M4-F doesn't support `vcvt.s32.f32` for `q` or `d` registers, only for `s` registers.**

The following *does* assemble ok with
`arm-none-eabi-as -mfpu=vfpv4  -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb`:

```
   vcvt.s32.f32 s8, s8, #0xf
   vcvt.s32.f32 s9, s9, #0xf
   vcvt.s32.f32 s10, s10, #0xf
   vcvt.s32.f32 s11, s11, #0xf
```